# Bluebird promise: How to avoid the runaway promise warning in a nested function?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

My code is as follows: (node.js code)

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird');

function promised()
{
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function backgroundJob()
{
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function doBackgroundJob()
{
    // this is an intentional runaway promise.
    backgroundJob()
    .catch(function (err)
    {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
}

function test()
{
    return promised()
    .then(function ()
    {
        doBackgroundJob();
        return null;  // without this, bluebird displays the warning
    });
}
```

`doBackgroundJob()` does a background job, so it does not need to return a promise. But since it creates a promise, when the function is called in a `then()`, without an explicit `return null` in the `then()`, bluebird prints the following warning to the console. 'Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it'.

This is somewhat unfair, since the caller does not need to know that the function uses a promise. How can I let bluebird to ignore the warning without `return null` in the `then()` in the caller?

I don't want to disable the warning, since it is quite useful.

Comment: you can disable warnings in general in bluebird: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html

Comment: @Thomas Thanks but I don't want to disable the warning. I've updated the question.

Comment: *"How can I let bluebird to ignore the warning"* but *"I don't want to disable the warning, since it is quite useful."* I'm confused.

Comment: @Thomas I want to ignore the warning only for this case. The warning is generally quite useful.

Comment: `promised().then(function(){ setTimeout(doBackgroundJob) });` I don't think you'd mind these few ms delay here. On the other hand, what's the problem with `return null`?

Comment: @Thomas Actually I have used the method you provided in some place, but I'm worried about the function calling order when multiple such calls are involved.

Comment: yes, order doesn't seem to be **guaranteed** for setTimeout. before we start building a workaround for that, again, what's wrong with `return null`?

Comment: @Thomas Please read my question (around the word 'unfair').

Comment: I've read that. I don't really understand why you consider that "unfair" but ok, and I don't see any argument what would be wrong with `return null`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to add the background `.then` *separately*, and return only the base promise:

```
function test() {
  const prom = promised();
  prom.then(doBackgroundJob);
  return prom;
}
```

while having `doBackgroundJob` return the promise (that proceeds to get discarded *in this implementation*):

```
function doBackgroundJob() {
  // this is an intentional runaway promise.
  return backgroundJob()
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    });
}
```

allowing other consumers of `doBackgroundJob` to possibly use the promise it returns if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

- `doBackgroundJob` is doing something asynchronous, so it should return a promise as usual to let the caller know when it is finished. Even if it already does all error-handling and guarantees to only fulfill the promise. The caller, knowing that it returns a promise, would use `return null` in `then` callbacks to avoid the warning.

  ```
  function doBackgroundJob() {
    return backgroundJob().catch(console.error);
  }
  ```
- If the caller should not know what `doBackgroundJobb` is doing, you can create the promise asynchronously (so that Bluebird doesn't notice) and return nothing (so that the caller doesn't notice):

  ```
  function doBackgroundJob() {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      // this is an intentional runaway promise.
      backgroundJob().catch(console.error);
    });
  }
  ```